# How to estimate virtual server size based on existing memory/cpu usage

Tags: server

I have been asked to estimate the cost of running an existing application on Amazon AWS. While diving in to this challenge, I have realized that it is far from being simple.

Amazon AWS has several cost estimate calculators asking number of vcpu/cores and Memory (RAM).

Does anyone know about a tool to gather this information? I imaging something that I could run in the background on our servers and report how much memory and cpu was used at peak time.

I don't know if that is the right way to go about it - any recommendations are welcome.

The existing servers are all running Ubuntu 16.04 and 18.04 and as system admin, I have root access.